# Mac OS X routing table protection

Tags: macos, vpn, routing

I'm looking for a way to protect my Mac OS 10.8 routing table. After connecting to my employer's network using the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client, a bunch of new routes are installed into my routing table, most of which I do not care for.  For example:

> 192.168.1     link#8     UCS     0     0     utun0

Which changes all local LAN traffic to use the new tunnel interface. This is trivially overridden using the following:

> route change 192.168.1.0/24 192.168.1.254

Which changes the route to:

```
192.168.1.0 link#5 UCS 1 0 en1
```

But as expected, the folks at Cisco are fairly clever - they've designed the application to periodically check and correct any changes to my routing table. Here's what happens shortly after I modify the routing table, from my Console:

> acvpnagent: A routing table change notification has been received. Starting automatic correction of the routing table.
>   acvpnagent: Function: executeRouteCmd File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/RouteTableMac.cpp
>   *The function continues to delete my routes and add the original routes*
>   acvpnagent: Automatic correction of the routing table has been successful.

So at this point, I would like to find a way to prevent acvpnagent from calling the route command after the initial tunnel is build - or to install routes that it cannot see/change, if possible.

Comment: Talk to the administrator of your client VPN solution (configuring AnyConnect). What you want is "Split Tunneling" and can be configured by your admin. They might provide it, if the security policy allows. If they don't want to allow it that's their decision. If you still deliberately change your routing table you are de facto connecting the Internet with your company's network via your computer against the intention of your employer. If something happens because of this, well, you explain to your company... Don't take this lightly unless you know exactly what you are doing!